# Создание графа из двух List

Tags: java, графы

Я пробую создать граф из двух листов.

У меня есть два листа.

Первый список книг выглядит как:

```
{"AA", "AB", "AC"}
```

Второй:

```
{"AA", "AB"}, {"AA", "AC"}
```

Я написал такой код:

```
        int i = 0;
        for (String librari : librariesList) {
            int j = 0;
            for (String dependencies: librariesDependencies) {
                if(librari.equals(dependencies)) {
                    graph.addEdge(i, j);
                    System.out.println(i + " " +  j);
                }
                j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Но понимаю что он не рабочий, так как он будет строить граф вида:

```
0 0
0 2
1 1
2 3
```

А не такой:

```
0 1
0 2
```

Что нужно исправить для получения правильного ответа?

Comment: `Второй:` необходимо указать, что это направленные связи, дуги графа. Читатели вопроса же не телепаты.

Comment: @MBo уже решил, код ужасный, но все же вышло. Спасибо за совет, впреть буду указывать

Answer (score 1):

Один из вариантов:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> vertices = List.of("AA", "AB", "AC");
        List<String> edges = List.of("AA", "AB", "AA", "AC");
        for (int j = 0; j < edges.size() / 2; j++) {
            System.out.println(
                    vertices.indexOf(edges.get(2 * j)) + " " +
                            vertices.indexOf(edges.get(2 * j + 1)));
        }
    }
}
```